# Intercom API CURL Getting error "code":"400","message":"User email, user_id or anonymous_id must be supplied"

Tags: php, curl, intercom, intercom.js

I want to update custom_attributes of Intercom through PHP CURL.

I am passing user_id and email as parameter still getting this error.
{"code":"400","message":"User email, user_id or anonymous_id must be supplied"}

```
try {
                $postData = json_encode(array(
                    "user_id" => strval($userDetails["id"]),
                    "email" => $userEmail,
                    "custom_attributes" => ['unsubscribed_from_emails' => 'true']
                ));

                $postHeader = [
                    'Authorization: Bearer <Access Token>',
                    'Accept: application/json',
                    'Content-Type: application/json -d'
                ];

                $curl = curl_init("https://api.intercom.io/users");
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, FALSE);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $postHeader);
                curl_exec($curl);
                curl_close($curl);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                error_log($e->getMessage());
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per php.net about the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS:

> This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded string like
> 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with the field name as key
> and field data as value. If value is an array, the Content-Type header
> will be set to multipart/form-data.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

But you pass a json instead.

Comment: Thanks @tania it was really helpful, I tried multipart/form-data but I was still getting same error so I implemented it through Intercom PHP api. Finally my code is working.